# Is there a way to combine processing power of 2 PC?

Tags: cluster

I have recently received an old PC from my friend. My current plan is to use it as a file server, but it feels like it is not fully utilizing the processing power of this second PC. Is there a way to connect this old PC to my main PC so I can use its CPU and/or ram for my daily use?

My main PC is using Ubuntu 22.04. I am planning to install Ubuntu in my second PC as well, but I am open to install other OS if it is necessary.

Comment: Simple answer: No. However, you can offload some tasks from the main machine to the other computer to reduce overall load. An example of this would be to use the file server for databases, torrenting, and other I/O heavy operations.

Comment: If you are running after computing power, I would suggest a bridged usb connection. Matigo is right, except if you are running your own program. You can code so that part of the program is executed in parallel on another machine (or on several other machines).